# How do I reliably determine if a file is already opened in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: c++, excel, com, automation

I am implementing an interface to Excel. I am using COM to automate Excel directly from C++. Most of my application is working reliably.

I however cannot detect if a file is already opened in Excel. If it is open, then I would like to inform the user to close it before running their simulation.

I am not using MFC, VB, or .NET. My solution has to work for Excel versions 97 to 2010. If I can know the version of Excel programmatically, it is OK to use different techniques for different excel versions.

I was looking for a file with the name "~$xxx" (where "xxx" is the original file name) in the same folder to determine if Excel has created a session lock. But this technique does not always work.

A similar question is once the simulation is started in my program, I want to prevent the user from opening the file in Write mode (read-only mode is OK).

Comment: Do you mean you want user to close file in excel only if it is some certain file? or any file? Does Excel open file in exclusive mode? Can you open it for writing?

Comment: My program will read/write the Excel file. I want the Excel to not interfere with the simulation. If the file is already opened in Excel, then user can type/edit the Excel file and then attempt to save it.

Comment: Can't you just try opening the file for write access?  That should fail if someone else has it open already: similarly if you succeed it should block anyone else from opening it for writing.

Comment: @Tim: Since it is an Excel file, I do not write it myself (I request COM to do it for me). But, I can try to open the file for writing to determine if it is OK for me to go ahead. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't work with C++ but using the same logic from VB.net, this C++ code probably should do what you want? I haven't tested it though... This also wouldn't need you to check for any specific Excel version as such. For `.xlsx` or any other extension, simply replace the extension below.

```
std::ofstream ofs("MyFile.xls");

if(ofs.is_open())
{
    //~~> File is ready for output
}
Else
{
    //~~> File is NOT ready for output
}
```

**EDIT**:

You also might want to see this?

**Topic**: FileInfo::IsReadOnly Property

**Link**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.isreadonly.aspx#Y0

**Quote From above link**

> Gets or sets a value that determines if the current file is read only.
>
> Namespace:  System.IO
>
> Assembly:  mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)

Comment: I accepted your answer because it works. However, there is a lag (delay) between me checking it and the COM interface opening the application. In between them, it is possible (though highly unlikely) that Excel opens the file.

Comment: I have something similar in Java already. I check if the file has read and write access. Then I open the file for writing in APPEND mode so that it does not accidentally destroy the original file. If the file can be opened, it is OK to write to it. This solution also has the same issue as your proposed solution though.